# Accessing Browser using RegistryEdit

Tags: java, browser, registry

I am accessing IE from my GUI when default browser is not set.that time i am accessing IE (when IE is not an default browser) by using path in RegisryEdit `Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Shell\\Associations\\UrlAssociations\\http\\UserChoice`. 
so IE is launching from GUI even when default browser is not set. But in windows XP i am using SOFTWARE\Classes\http\shell\open\command this path.It is not working? Is that path is correct.

1)`Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Shell\\Associations\\UrlAssociations\\http\\UserChoice`--progid is IE.HTTP  in windows 7

2)`SOFTWARE\\Classes\\http\\shell\\open\\command`---Nothing is shown like windows 7.

What should I do to access IE(when it is not set as default)from windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read path from here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

The IE installed path is stored in 'path' value of this key.

Comment: Thanks.Can't we have IE.HTTP in HKEY_CURRENT_USER directory like WIN7?